# O Recycler View está tendo elementos substituídos quando eu faço uma nova requisição de dados

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Estou com problemas ao fazer requisições e colocar o resultado no Recycler View. Sempre que eu faço uma nova requisição o Recycler View tem os elementos substituídos ao invés de preservar o que já foi chamado e só adicionar mais elementos na lista.

Meu código que faz a requisição está assim:

```
class Api (val recyclerView: RecyclerView) : MainActivity(){
    private lateinit var adapter: Adapter
    private val remote3 = Connection.createService(Repository::class.java)

    fun getResponsesFromRepository(page: Int) {
        val callPostRepository: Call<Domain.Items> = remote3.list("language:Java", "stars", page)

        callPostRepository.enqueue(object : Callback<Domain.Items> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Domain.Items>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                println(t.message)
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<Domain.Items>,
                response: Response<Domain.Items>
            ) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    var repo: Domain.Items = response.body()!!
                    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(instance)
                    adapter = Adapter(repo)
                    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

O código da Main Activity está assim:

```
open class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var count = -1
    private lateinit var recycler: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var api: Api
    private lateinit var loading: View

    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: MainActivity
            private set
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        instance = this
        recycler = findViewById(R.id.rec)
        api = Api(recycler)
        loading = findViewById(R.id.frame_loading)

        recycler.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)

                if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) && newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    fetchNewData(api, loading)
                }
            }
        })

    fun fetchNewData(api: Api, view: View) {
        api.getResponsesFromRepository(count)
        count++
    }
}
```

Sempre que eu vou até o final da página ele carrega mais elementos, mas ele não acrescenta esses elementos no recycler view e sim substituí os que já foram carregados, se alguém me der uma luz de como resolver isso eu agradeço kkkkkkkkk

Answer (score 0):

O que voce pode fazer:

```
 private lateinit var adapter: Adapter
 private val remote3 = Connection.createService(Repository::class.java)
 private val listaDeAlgumaCoisa = arrayListOf<Item>()


...

if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    var repo: Domain.Items = response.body()!!
                    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(instance)
                    listaDeAlgumaCoisa.addAll(repo)
                    adapter = Adapter(listaDeAlgumaCoisa)
                    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
                }
```

No entanto, o que voce deveria fazer é criar uma classe que herde Adapter() e la dentro tenha uma função que seja para adicionar mais items.
Tenho um exemplo na minha primeira [pokedex](https://github.com/joavilati/Pokedex_Kotlin/blob/ead178f0b6715db199c79c57a1594a71a8067b42/app/src/main/java/com/example/pokedexagoravai/ui/PokemonAdapter.kt#L38) em android